# Memory allocation between C and Java

Tags: java, c, memory-management, out-of-memory

I developed the Eratosthene's Sieve algorithm in C and Java, but I encountered some problems.

To manage the array of prime numbers I used an array of char for C (8 bit for each element) and an array of boolean for Java (8 bit for each element).

When I try to calculate the prime numbers until N=1,000,000,000 (so there is an array of N elements), the Java application works great (I expanded the heap size to 1,5GB). When I try to do the same with the C application it runs out of memory (the limit is N=680,000,000).

When I run both the applications with the same N=500,000,000 I checked and both occupy about 512MB of RAM, so if the Java application works fine with N=1,000,000,000 I don't understand why the C application fails to run immediately.

Is there an "option" for C like the "-Xmx1536m" of Java that I don't know?

I have 4GB of RAM and I use Windows 7 64bit. I also checked the sizeof(size_t) value and it is 32, so I guess I can rightly allocate 4GB of memory.

**EDIT:** I tried the 64bit version of Cygwin and now it works fine with N=1,000,000,000. Is there a reason for this? I guess 1GB of memory "requires" 32bit, not 64...

Here there are the applications' sources.

**Java:**

```
int N = 1000000000;
int m;

boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[N + 1];
for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
    isPrime[i] = true;
}

for (int i = 2; i*i <= N; i++) {
    if (isPrime[i]) {
        for (int j = i; (m = i*j) <= N; j++) {
            isPrime[m] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**C:**

```
int N = 1000000000;
int i, j, m;
char *isPrime;
isPrime = malloc(sizeof(char)*(N+1));

for (i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
    isPrime[i] = 1;
}

for (i = 2; i*i <= N; i++) {
    if (isPrime[i]) {
        for (j = i; (m = i*j) <= N; j++) {
            isPrime[m] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling the C program targeting 32-bit or 64-bit architecture?

Comment: @cdhowie How can I check that? I'm using Netbeans 7.2 with Cygwin. Nevermind, I found it.

Comment: Just a note: you should always check the return value of malloc()

Comment: I have not used Netbeans so I don't know how to check it within that IDE, but I would expect it to be alongside other C compiler options such as optimization level, warning level, include paths, linked libraries, etc.

Comment: I tried to choose 64 or 32 bit, but it didn't fix the problem...

Comment: Why aren't you using a [bit vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array)? Java has a nice implementation called [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). You could probably find one for C online, or write one yourself pretty easily.

Comment: (Or, if C++ is an option, `std::vector<bool>` is specialized to be a bit vector.)

Comment: I'm going to check those implementations, thanks!

Comment: @cdhowie - If C++ is an option, then he could just use [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) there as well. The difference between `std::vector<bool>` and `std::bitset` is that `std::vector<bool>` can change sizes, but he has a static size so it's not really necessary.

Comment: Now I correctly used the Cygwin 64bit version and it works. I edited my question, but I can't figure it out why it requires 64bit version...

Comment: It might be because there isn't a contiguous block of 1GB worth of addresses in your process' 32-bit address space.  The odds of this happening in a 64-bit address space are dramatically lower.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I still feel it's kinda weird by the way :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because of how memory allocation differs between the C runtime and the JVM. The C runtime guarantees a contiguous block of memory for array allowing you to do pointer arithmetic to access array elements. There are no such guarantees in Java which perhaps allows larger arrays to be allocated.